# Task :react-native-deepar:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar FAILED #4025

Tags: android, react-native, deepar

> Error while evaluating property 'hasLocalAarDeps' of task ':react-native-deepar:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar'

How to get off from this issue?

I want a solution of this problem for making a release build

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any help?